# How do I determine why my town house floors are uneven all over?

Tags: flooring, joists, subfloor, level

My townhome, built 1988, has floors that are not level throughout the home. In the bedroom if a dresser is against the wall on two opposite walls they have an extreme forward tilt; but, on the other two opposite walls, it’s completely fine / level. There is also [different] tilting downstairs, but not in the room immediately below this upper bedroom. Some rooms are fine, but on both the top and mid levels there are specific areas that are extremely not level.

How do I fix this, what could it be? I’m thinking it could be a joists issue. Also, I’m about to get new carpet throughout, what can I look for when the old carpet is taken up?

Comment: More likely foundation than framing. As @crip659 said, get a pro, likely a general contractor, out for an opinion.

Comment: Have you asked your neighbors if their floors are buckling as well? In a multi-unit dwelling (even if you own your part), you're probably going to need an engineer to design a solution and a licensed contractor to do the work so that it doesn't negatively impact _other_ people's residences. Mess up your own, stand alone house? Your problem. Cause the side wall of _my_ house to lean due to your misunderstanding/mistake? Not a good thing at all, possible lawsuits...

Comment: Also, make sure you get this fixed _before_ installing new carpet - it'll have to get pulled up as they're fixing floors anyway...

Comment: Built _how_? Built _where_? What's "extreme"? Please revise to add detail about your structure, location, climate, etc.

Comment: Is all of the bad sloping aligned with the floor joist spanning direction? Joists should get designed for length divided by 360 deflection between the end supports, e.g. (20ft)(12in/ft)/360 = 0.67". The purpose of this spec is to avoid too much slope in the floor due to deflection. Your description of both ends heavily sloped to center indicates a deflection problem if aligned with joist span direction. Has there been any remodeling? Can you maybe confirm that some mechanicals route through the joists, where there's a good chance that some joists have been mutilated?

Comment: Do you know if your joists are sawn lumber (e.g. 2×10s) versus I-joists (i.e. two lengths of wood top and bottom with some kind of paneling material between them)?

Comment: "Different tilt"? What does that mean?

Answer (score 3):

I can only offer general suggestions with what little I know about your structure.

1. Determine whether you have *tilt* or *sag* in the floor. Us a straightedge, level, or carpenter's line to see if the floor is leaning to one side or if it's lower between the walls. A flat floor that's tilted suggests a settling foundation. A sagging floor suggests inadequate floor framing.
2. Investigate the other floors. Compare with above. This also helps narrow down the scope of the problem.
3. Investigate the *walls*. Use a level 4ft. (~1.5m) or longer to determine if they're plumb (vertical). Check many points on both of your home's primary axes. This also helps distinguish between foundation and framing issues.
4. Look at windows and doors. Are they square (equal dimension on the diagonals)? Are they binding? Are gaps parallel and uniform? This adds evidence to the type of problem.
5. Look for water damage, rot, and evidence of insect activity. Remove HVAC vents for access to the framing. Look at drywall and trim around the basement. Look at the bases of your utility equipment for rust or stains.
6. Look at the foundation and framing directly. Do you see cracks? Joint separation? Angles other than 90°? Damage debris? All those clues together begin to paint a picture of the overall problem.
7. Look outside. Do you see soil movement? Is the siding still straight and level? Is there evidence of movement in the paint? Do the roof lines appear straight? Again, these can be enlightening pieces to the puzzle.

In all cases record specific dimensions, ideally on a drawing of your home. Every home has some deviation from perfect. It's the extent and type of this deviation that's telling. If you do consult an expert this information will be very helpful.

After you've done all that you should have a sense of what's happening. Then you can consider remediation solutions.

Comment: Note that your first concern should be stopping this from getting worse/recurring, or any "fix" may just be temporary.